# Add Convert to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to figure out how to add the following data to my json object. Could someone show me how to do this.

{
    "main_img":"Base64 String"
}

However, the following is the result of using this code, to come out.

```
final int COMPRESSION_QUALITY = 100;
String encodedImage;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY,
byteArrayBitmapStream);
byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
encodedImage = "data:image/JPEG;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
jObject.put("main_img", result);
```

{
    "main_img":"Base64 String

It is displayed with }, " is missing.

Comment: If that is the issue, then Before returning encodedImage, Just add the missing things, encodedImage += "\"}".

Comment: you put result to Jobject , at here i dnt knw what is ur result